# How to JSON encode an array with French accents?

Tags: php, json

There are many threads about this but none of them helped me solve this problem.

```
$array=array(
"dépendre"=>"to depend",
"dire"=>"to say",
"distraire"=>"distracted",
"être"=>"to be (being)",
);
```

Gets encoded like this with `json_encode` :

```
"d\u00e9pendre":"to depend","dire":"to say","distraire":"distracted","\u00eatre":"to be (being)"
```

So far I have tried this:

```
array_walk_recursive($array,function($value,$key) {
     $key = urlencode(utf8_decode($key));
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

`json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

You should get this result;

```
{
  "dépendre":"to depend",
  "dire":"to say",
  "distraire":"distracted",
  "être":"to be (being)"
}
```

Comment: Wow that works. That was a lot simpler than all the other stuff I came across.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the result from the following code:

```
<?php
$x=array(
    "dépendre"=>"to depend",
    "dire"=>"to say",
    "distraire"=>"distracted",
    "être"=>"to be (being)",
);

$encoded = json_encode($x);

var_dump($x);

var_dump(json_decode($encoded, true));
```

The string you get in your question is a correctly escaped JSON and could be successfully decoded.